# Was Artemis Fowl based on any specific prodigy?

Tags: inspiration, artemis-fowl, eoin-colfer

Artemis Fowl, (anti)hero of the eponymous novel series by Eoin Colfer, is a self-described criminal genius and prodigy. He is known to have broken numerous age records, perhaps most notably that of youngest person ever to steal the *Fairy Thief* painting (in book 4).

**Is there any evidence to suggest that Colfer based him on any specific prodigy/ies,** either real-life ones or from earlier fictional works? Or was he just a "juvenile criminal genius" with no specific pre-existing inspirations?

Answer (score 11):

It is stated [here](http://www.smh.com.au/entertainment/books/a-fond-farewell-to-artemis-fowl-20120629-218vp.html):

> his brother Donal's favourite conversation-starter in the pub: ''Artemis Fowl is based on me.''

and

> ''So I took this character, my brother Donal, the little 12-year-old Bond villain, and said, 'What if he kidnaps one of the leprechauns for the crock of gold?''

So apparently, Artemis is based on Colfer's brother Donal.

Comment: Interesting, and not what I was expecting. Is there any evidence of AF being based on someone else as well, perhaps someone who was more of a prodigy? Many complex fictional characters are inspired by more than just a single figure in real life.